# How do I format the time in the left column?

Tags: fullcalendar

In the left column of the day and week view, the hours are displayed as '12am' upto '11pm', etc.

Which option is used to format this column? I want it in 24-hours format.

Answer (score 1):

The option you want is `slotLabelFormat`, e.g:

```
slotLabelFormat: "HH:mm"
```

will produce a time in 24hr format. You can use any format string that momentJS supports.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotLabelFormat/ and http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ for more details.

Comment: How does this work for v4? I've tried to supply a string but just get errors.

Comment: @MrWiLofDoom If you don't tell me what value you supplied or what your errors are, it's hard to have any idea what exactly fullCalendar doesn't like...but having said that, have you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/slotLabelFormat? It seems fairly clear to me that a string is not what it expects in v4.